# How to type two TeX examples of long Regex in Book JavaScript: The Good Parts?

Tags: verbatim

The following two examples are taken from Douglas Crockford's famous book, Page 69 (or 66) and 76. I don't know how to type them in TeX.

Example 1:

```
    Those are the factors of the regular expression parse\_url.\footnote{
    When you press them all together again, it is visually quite confusing:  \\
    /^(?:([A-Za-z]+):)?(\/{0,3})([0-9.\-A-Za-z]+)(?::(\d+))?(?:\/([^?#]*))?(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?$/
    }
```

Example 2:

```
    (?:!|"|#|\$|%|&|'|\(|\)|\*|\+|,|-|\.|\/|:|;|<|=|>|@|\[|\\|]|\^|_|` |\{|\||\}|~)
```

I have tried `\texttt{ }` and `\verb`, and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You cannot use `\verb` inside a foot note.

Comment: Maybe not, when I tried  \verb@...@, it shows:  ! Missing $ inserted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\verb`, but you have to find delimiters which don't appear in your regex. You could use e.g. `1` as delimiter: `\verb1...1`

For verbatim text in footnotes, you can e.g. use the `fancyvrb` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\VerbatimFootnotes

\begin{document}
Those are the factors of the regular expression parse\_url.\footnote{
    When you press them all together again, it is visually quite confusing:  \\
    \verb1/^(?:([A-Za-z]+):)?(\/{0,3})([0-9.\-A-Za-z]+)(?::(\d+))?(?:\/([^?#]*))?(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?$/1
    }

\verb1(?:!|"|#|\$|%|&|'|\(|\)|\*|\+|,|-|\.|\/|:|;|<|=|>|@|\[|\\|]|\^|_|` |\{|\||\}|˜)1
\end{document}
```